# Can't we use "grid-column: 1 / -1;" with "grid-auto-flow: column;" in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have an element grid with an undetermined number of columns, I need the second line to take all the with of the layout.

I have tried to use `grid-column: 1 / -1;`. But this property do not seem to work with `grid-auto-flow: column;` as it work with a more simple `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;`.

I made a code pen to explain the problem In a simple context :

https://codepen.io/4dr1en/pen/abQGQeb

Comment: perhaps this can help, explicit vs implicit grid, https://www.quackit.com/css/grid/tutorial/explicit_vs_implicit_grid.cfm

Comment: `display: flex` works better in this scenario.

Comment: For the simple reason that the css doesn't know which is the last row unless you tell it how many there are.

Comment: Grid auto flow column here is irrelevant regarding width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a grid in that case. By using a simple flexbox it's way easier:

```js
var tabListElements = document.getElementsByClassName('tabListElement');
var tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-id]');
changeTab('tab_1');

for (var i = 0; i < tabListElements.length; i++) {
  tabListElements[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
    changeTab(e.target.id);
  });
}

function changeTab(tabId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) {
    tabContents[i].style.display = tabContents[i].getAttribute('data-tab-id') == tabId ? "block" : "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.tabList {
    display: flex;
}

.tabListElement {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    background: lightgray;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

section {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabList">
  <div id="tab_1" class="tabListElement">TAB 1</div>
  <div id="tab_2" class="tabListElement">TAB 2</div>
  <div id="tab_3" class="tabListElement">TAB 3</div>
  <div id="tab_4" class="tabListElement">TAB 4</div>
</div>

<section data-tab-id="tab_1">
  content of tab 1
</section>

<section data-tab-id="tab_2">
  content of tab 2
</section>

<section data-tab-id="tab_3">
  content of tab 3
</section>

<section data-tab-id="tab_4">
  content of tab 4
</section>
```

with some js you can create a logic to switch tabs.

You can link the tab button to the correct tab section by setting the `id` and the custom data field `data-tab-id`.

Is this the solution you are looking for?

Comment: I was looking for a solution that didn't involve changing the HTML. I finally found a solution using Flex as you said.


https://codepen.io/4dr1en/pen/MWzGLJj